# When does this converse of Vopěnka's principle hold?

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors, locally-presentable-categories

The $n$Lab page on coreflective subcategories cites a theorem of Adamek and Rosický showing that every colimit-closed full subcategory of a locally presentable category is coreflective. My question is, when does the converse hold? If I have a coreflective subcategory which is closed under colimits in the supercategory, how can I tell that it is locally presentable? Does the structure of the inclusion and coreflector tell us anything about this?

Comment: Note that every coreflective subcategory is closed under colimits.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize that. In that case, is there any property of a coreflective subcategory that hints at its supercategory being locally presentable? It sounds like there isn't much to be said about local presentability in terms of just a single coreflective subcategory.

Comment: No, I wouldn't think so. Why should there be? The more natural question seems to be: if a cocomplete category has all its colimit-closed subcategories coreflective, is it guaranteed to be locally presentable?

Comment: @KevinCarlson I was just being hopeful, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

This does not look like a converse of your principle, and unless I misunderstood you it seems false.

Indeed, any category is both co-reflective and colimit-closed in itself, but has no reason of being locally presentable.

Comment: Yes, perhaps I worded my question poorly. Suppose $L:C\hookrightarrow D$ has a right adjoint $R$, and furthermore suppose all colimits of functors factoring through the inclusion remain in the subcategory. My question is, what properties of $D$ force it to be locally presentable? I suppose this is not the converse as previously stated because I do not require every full inclusion to be coreflective. My apologies for the confusion.